# How to implement conditional requirements in a conanfile?

Tags: jenkins, conan

We have projects that require different Conan packages during unit tests (i.e. mocks) than during normal compilation.
Is there a best practice how to implement conditional requirements in a conanfile for such a use case?

We have tried using switches with environment variables like this:

```
class project_a(ConanFile):
....
    def requirements()
        if os.getenv('UNIT_TESTING') == 'true':
            self.requires('mock_for_testing/1.0.0@someuser/somechannel
...
```

But then the requirements for project_a are always changed during unit testing.
So also when a project is tested, that consumes project_a.

Comment: Conan is not focused on running unit test when building packages, it's focused on packaging artifacts like libraries, headers and binaries. However, there is a prepared environment variable which can be used for unit tests: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/env_vars.html#env-vars-conan-run-tests. You should use `tools.get_env` instead and take a look on https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#develop which can be used to detected when you are building or consuming a package, so you can use as condition to add or not a requirement.

Comment: Thanks @uilianries for your comment. We will use the `self.develop` attribute to identify, if the current package is built or consumed together with the check for the unit testing env. Could you please post your comment, then I would mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conan is not focused on running unit test when building packages, it's focused on packaging artifacts like libraries, headers and binaries.

However, there is a prepared environment variable which can be used for unit tests: [CONAN_RUN_TESTS](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/env_vars.html#env-vars-conan-run-tests). You should use [tools.get_env](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/tools.html#tools-get-env) instead.

Also, take a look on [self.develop](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#develop) which can be used to detected when you are building or consuming a package, so you can use as condition to add or not a requirement:

```py
def requirements()
    if self.develop:
        self.requires('mock/1.0.0@user/channel')
```

Then, the package will be consumed only when running the command [create](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/creator/create.html).